# How to find which file is responsible for "Can t recycle x to match place"

Tags: r, vctrs

I encountered the following error while performing the loop function in order to import my data into R

> Error in vctrs::data_frame(): ! Can't recycle users (size 117) to
> match places (size 3)

The code I used is as follows:

```
filesU <- list.files("C:/Users/artde/OneDrive/Documents/Master R/Master R/Project 1/Json/Daran_API_U/")

tweetsU = fromJSON("C:/Users/artde/OneDrive/Documents/Master R/Master R/Project 1/Json/Daran_API_U/users_1344795476151971842.json", flatten=T)

filesU <- filesU[-1] 

for (file in 1:length(filesU)) { 
    tweetsU_loop = fromJSON(paste0("C:/Users/artde/OneDrive/Documents/Master R/Master R/Project 1/Json/Daran_API_U/", 
                                   filesU[file])) 
    tweetsU = bind_rows(tweetsU,tweetsU_loop) 
}
```

However I keep getting this error after performing the bind part

> Error in vctrs::data_frame(): ! Can't recycle users (size 117) to
> match places (size 3). Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error
> occurred.

With another data set this has worked perfectly so far, however in this dataset it seems that there is a file that creates a problem and does not allow the loop and bind function to work
I understand that is due to one of these files having a different length or value compared to the other files, but considering i have 640 files, i was wondering if there was a way to pinpoint the responsible one (there is no obvious one, which has a very different name or is way heavier than every other)

All the files are in Json

Comment: Can't you tell from the value of `file` when the loop crashes?

Comment: So if i remove the file 117, the error appears again, with the same number, it will just give the value 117 to a different file

Comment: No, not the number in the error message, but the value of the loop variable `file` just after it crashes. `filesU[file]` will be the problem file.

Comment: If i perform a backtrace i get this 


Backtrace:
    x
 1. +-dplyr::bind_rows(tweetsU, tweetsU_loop)
 2. | \-dplyr:::map(...)
 3. |   \-base::lapply(.x, .f, ...)
 4. |     \-dplyr FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 5. |       \-vctrs::data_frame(!!!.x, .name_repair = "minimal")
 6. \-vctrs::stop_incompatible_size(...)
 7.   \-vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
 8.     \-vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
 9.       \-rlang::abort(message, class = c(class, "vctrs_error"), ..., call = vctrs_error_call(call))

But i am unsure on how to find the file the value of the loop variable

Comment: Sorry for the many edits
If i run file by itself it gives me a value of 1

Comment: So it is crashing on the `bind_rows` of the first file, which perhaps means that `tweetsU_loop` is not a dataframe, because the JSON file does not represent a simple rectangular array of data. You will need to have a look at the structure of the first `tweetsU_loop` and then work out the best way of merging them all, as `bind_rows` is probably not the way to go in this case.

Comment: Thank you !
So to resume, there is something in this code line that isn't working, especially regarding the bind row function 
tweetsU_loop = fromJSON(paste0("C:/Users/artde/OneDrive/Documents/Master R/Master R/Project 1/Json/Daran_API_U/", 
                                   filesU[file]))
Thank you very much for your help and your patience

Comment: I think the code is working, it is just that the JSON files are not producing the sort of data structure that you expect. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you !
You were right, the structure is different from expected